# Any ideas how to trigger the breakpoint inside a callback to Array.prototype.every?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, chrome-debugging

I had followed this [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) and installed [chrome debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) (non related to the guide) on VS Code - I've modified `index.tsx` to contain this code:

```
function f(s:string) :boolean
{
    return s != undefined;
}

function f1()
{
    const v : string = String();

    if(v) {alert("IF");}

    const q = Array<string>(9);

    if(!q.every(f)) {alert("BOOLEAN");}
}

f1();
```

I've set a breakpoint inside `f` but it's never triggered. On the other hand is not being marked as grey while debugging. What am I missing?

Any breakpoint inside `f1` is being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

`Array<string>(9)` creates an array with 9 empty slots, and [the `every` method skips empty slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Description), so `f` is never called and a breakpoint set in `f` won't be reached.